How can I take apart a bookshelf?
I am trying to take apart the bookshelf in the photo (I need to be able to transport it in the car). I have undone the screws, but additionally it seesm to have nails and potentially glue. Is there a way of taking the different parts apart without damaging the wood? What tools do I need?
Thank you very much in advance.



You don't, unless you consider yourself qualified to have built it in the first place. Restoring it to its present condition takes that kind of skill.

Alternative solutions - hire a trailer to tow with the car.  Or hire a light truck/ute/pickup.  If the destination isn't too far away, walk the bookshelf there with a sackbarrow. CBNAA

This would be a better question for the Woodworking stack.
If it is glued... Glue joints can be stronger than the wood, and just applying force risks damage.
It appears to be solid wood rather than ply and MDF, so it might be old enough to have been built with hide glue. If so, the pros use steam (eg wrapping the joint in damp fabric and carefully applying a hot air gun) to heat and rehydrate the glue, softening it so the pieces can be separated for repair.
Modern adhesives are less cooperative.
It is possible that part of what's holding it together at this point is that it was varnished as a complete piece. If so, a razor knife at the joined edges might release it.
Personally, I would suggest finding a friend with a minivan or truck, or renting one for the day. It's a nice piece; I wouldn't want to risk damaging it.

You can take it apart, but it will probably not be worth the work. You will need a couple of thin pry bars, a chisel and a small hammer.
Work your way around the bookcase, prying open one mm at a time. Once done, remove the nails from the pieces.
I've done this a few times when restoring valuable furniture, and it takes an enormous amount of time and patience.
If you are just trying to save money,  rent a truck.

Agreed, that is not a piece of furniture made to be broken down for transport.  Doing so may make the furniture unsuitable for use when reassembled.  Consider renting or borrowing a truck.

You forgot "and luck".

@Cheery - Unless you are the originator of that pry bar photo you need to provide attribution to the source as required by Stack Exchange guidelines. Please update your answer accordingly.

How nice do you want it to be afterwards? A multitool will tear through any joint, and you can screw it back togther afterwards. It'll look a bit rough though?

There are two types of modern mass-produced furniture:

Factory Assembled - These will often include screws, glue and nails. These are usually not designed to be disassembled.

Ready to Assemble (RTA) - IKEA is the most well-known of these, but there are plenty of others. While not specifically designed to be disassembled, they usually can be disassembled and reassembled without too much trouble. In particular, nails are typically used only for holding thin backing (non-structural) and glue is typically used to give extra strength to dowels. But the primary structural pieces are screws, cams and other specialized hardware - all of which is normally reversible without special tools. That helps for disassembly and also for "oops" moments in initial assembly.


One clue that a piece of furniture is RTA is if you see cams like this replacement from Amazon:

but it is possible to have factory assembled furniture with cams, and this is no guarantee of easy disassembly.
In the end though, the simplest thing is often to borrow a pickup truck from a friend for an hour.

I agree with you answer in general. However, in most IKEA furniture I built (bookshelves, dressers, closets, ...) the "thin backing (non-structural)" is very much structural in that it keeps the piece from toppling over like a house of cards by keeping the bottom, sides and top at right angles.

@arne is correct; those thin backing pieces resist racking/torsional forces across the joints of a piece by being on a perpendicular plane where those forces are exerted as tension. Try pulling a piece of paper apart; it's actually remarkably strong in that dimension. I've seen lots of RTA furniture fail because people were sloppy about properly attaching these "decorative" backing pieces, and they almost always blame the material rather than their construction.

There are more kinds of furniture than those two.

@einpoklum There are. But broadly speaking, most mass-market furniture falls in these categories.

You can't put humpty dumpty together again.
This looks like something I might make. The bookshelf does not look like it was designed to be taken apart to me. It looks like it might be glued to me. I would have glued it. Though they might have just glued the bottom together IDK... cannot see it that well.
That being said, furniture that was made to be disassembled/resembled either relies on screws, or joinery to hold it together. I don't see evidence of either.
If it is glued. Taking it apart will break it, and you won't be able to get it back together again.
if it is nailed. You can take it apart if you are careful. But it won't be the same when you put it back together.
Source: I am an amateur furniture/cabinet maker.
As it is right now, it looks good. To join the chorus A U-Haul or similar vehicle is cheap to rent, and will cost less time/money then fixing this after your try to take it apart and break it.
